# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Wifi Connectivity Issue

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, connection, bug-reporting

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on my Haier Y11B laptop. But after installing my WiFi works sometimes or sometimes it don't work. Sometimes it shows all the WiFi network available around me and allows me to connect. But after sometime it lose its signal strength and don't shows any WiFi connection at all or shows very week signal which is unable to connect. Even if I keep it near the WiFi router signal strength is same. But when i uses the Windows or uses try-Ubuntu option my WiFi works 100% fine.

I tried restarting network manager by running `sudo service network-manager restart`. But most of the times it also don't works.

Plz find my Wireless Cards info below

```
qasim@Haier-Y11B:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: wlx7cc709caf90d
       serial: 7c:c7:09:ca:f9:0d
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxudriverversion=4.15.0-36-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
qasim@Haier-Y11B:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

kindly guide me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!
I solved it by creating an executable file (* .sh) with the following codes:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean restart
sudo /etc/init.d/networking force-reload
sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
```

----- copy code in an empty file ----

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# NB: **First install nscd** with sudo apt-get install nscd

# run this command to flush dns cache:
sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean restart
# or use:
sudo /etc/init.d/networking force-reload
# Flush nscd dns cache:
sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
# If you wanted to refresh your settings you could disable and then run
sudo service network-manager restart

echo "DNS Flushed!";
```

---- save as something.sh ----

Execute your bash file in terminal with:

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/something.sh    
./path/to/your/something.sh
```

Comment: It is better not to put sudo inside the script. Then run `sudo ./path/to/your/something.sh`.